# Why do changes made in foreach to a Linq grouping select get ignored unless I add ToList()?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-group

I have the following method.

```
public IEnumerable<Item> ChangeValueIEnumerable()
    {
        var items = new List<Item>(){
            new Item("Item1", 1),
            new Item("Item2", 1),
            new Item("Item3", 2),
            new Item("Item4", 2),
            new Item("Item5", 3)
        };

        var groupedItems = items.GroupBy(i => i.Value)
            .Select(x => new Item(x.First().Name, x.Key));

        foreach (var item in groupedItems)
        {
            item.CalculatedValue = item.Name + item.Value;
        }

        return groupedItems;
    }
```

Into the `groupedItems` collection the `CalculatedValue`s are null. However if I add a `ToList()` to the `Select` sentence after the `GroupBy` the `CalculatedValue`s has values.
for example:

```
 var groupedItems = items.GroupBy(i => i.Value)
            .Select(x => new Item(x.First().Name, x.Key)).ToList();
```

So, the question is. Why is this? I want to know the reason for this, the solution for me is add a `ToList()`

Update: The defition of `Item` class is the following

```
 public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public string CalculatedValue { get; set; }

    public Item(string name, int value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the definition of the `Item` class?

Comment: @Enigmativity I already added the Item class. Thanks

Comment: As an aside, by convention, since `Item` accepts constructor parameters, you should consider marking the associated properties `Name` and `Value` as `private set`, or even better, using `readonly` backing fields to express immutability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var groupedItems = items.GroupBy(i => i.Value)
    .Select(x => new Item(x.First().Name, x.Key));
```

Here, `groupedItems` doesn't actually hold any items. The `IEnumerable<T>` returned by `Select` represents a computation - to be precise, it represents the result of mapping `items` to a new set of items by applying the function `x => new Item(x.First().Name, x.Key)`.

Each time you iterate over `groupedItems`, the function will be applied and a new set of items will be created.

```
var groupedItems = items.GroupBy(i => i.Value)
    .Select(x => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating new item");
        return new Item(x.First().Name, x.Key));
    }

foreach(var item in groupedItems);
foreach(var item in groupedItems);
```

This code, for example, will print "Creating new item" twice for each item in `items`.

In your code, you're setting the `CalculatedValue` of an *ephemeral* item. When the foreach loop is done, the items are gone.

By calling `ToList`, you're turning the "computation" into an actual collection of items.

Instead of calling `ToList`, you could alternatively create *another computation* that represents a new set of items with their `CalculatedValue` property set. This is the *functional* way.

```
Func<Item, Item> withCalculatedValue =
    item => {
        item.CalculatedValue = item.Name + item.Value;
        return item;
    };

return items.GroupBy(i => i.Value)
        .Select(x => new Item(x.First().Name, x.Key))
        .Select(withCalculatedValue);
```

Or simply use object initializers

```
return items.GroupBy(i => i.Value)
        .Select(x => new Item(x.First().Name, x.Key) { CalculatedValue = x.First().Name + x.Key });
```

If you want to do a little bit more research on the topic of objects that hold computations, google the term "Monad", but be prepared to be confused.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to dcastro's good answer, viz that the change (mutation) made to items in the `for` loop occur in a *first* iteration of `groupedItems`, which are *not stored* by anything, and that if a caller of `ChangeValueIEnumerable` iterates the returned `IEnumerable`, the original `groupedItems` will be executed for a second time.

Note that you can avoid the issue without using `ToList()` by doing the projection in the `Select`:

```
var groupedItems = items.GroupBy(i => i.Value)
    .Select(x => new Item(x.First().Name, x.Key)
    {
        CalculatedValue = x.First().Name + x.Key
    });

return groupedItems;
```

Comment: I amended my answer at roughly the same time you posted yours :) +1